# Flask: Post Response(json.dumps(dict)) not returning json

Tags: python, flask

For some reason, I am not getting a json as my response. What am I doing wrong? I want to be able to get the result dict when I call the post function but all I am getting back is a 200 status code indicating everything is ok.

```
@app.route('/data', methods=['POST'])
def data():
    if request.method == "POST":  
        result = {
                    "data": {
                        "name": "First, Last",
                        "value": 1
                      }
                    }
        return Response(json.dumps(result), mimetype='application/json; charset=utf-8')
    else:
        abort(404)
```

I have tried different ways to return the json obect:

```
return json.dumps(result)

return jsonify(result)
```

But nothing works :\

Comment: Why do you think that response doesn't contain json? Your code return json. How do you make request?

Comment: I ran your code and made request via rest client. It's ok.

Comment: @Budulianin I basically am running the application on my localhost and then using ngrok to get a working url. I am calling post with the postman chrome app but I am not getting back a json at all. How have you done it?

Comment: Flask==0.12, Python 2.7.13, my code https://codeshare.io/ampnrp
I run it thru python -m flask run, I make request thru Restlet Client - DHC.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but could it be, that the url `/data` is used somewhere else and you never call this specific function.
Can you add some logging or prints in the function to verify that the function is called. 
I tried your your code with python 2.7 and Flask 0.12 in a simple example and it works.

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import json
from flask import Flask, jsonify, Response, request

# Initialize the Flask application
app = Flask(__name__)

# Set some configuration to the flask ap
app.config['DEBUG'] = True


# Default route for /
@app.route("/data", methods=['POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == "POST":
        result = {
            "data": {
                "name": "First, Last",
                "value": 1
            }
        }
        # Both worked 
        # return jsonify(result)
        return Response(json.dumps(result), mimetype='application/json; charset=utf-8')
    else:
        return abort(404)
```

Exported the file as FLASK_APP
`export FLASK_APP=server.py`
and run the server
`flask run`